# What is the default time-out for http requests using the http dart library?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, http, timeout

I am using the [http dart library](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to perform REST API requests (GET, POST) to a remote server.

When the server is not running the requests time-out.
Is there a default time limit for the requests, after which a `Connection timed out` exception is thrown? If yes, which is that time limit?

We tried logging the timestamp before and after the request was performed. The difference of the 2 timestamps was 30ms. But we do not know if this is the default configuration of the dart library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default timeout for an HTTP request made via `dart:io`'s `HttpClient` is dependent on the default timeout for the OS, so it's hard to say exactly what timeout should be expected.

However, you can configure the timeout by setting [`connectionTimeout` on your `HttpClient`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.5/dart-io/HttpClient/connectionTimeout.html) instance to a non-null `Duration` if you want to have a consistent connection timeout duration across platforms.

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks a lot for your response it really helps.

Is the default timeout on Android and iOS known?
And in Android does it also depends on the manufacturer's OS?

Comment: The timeouts are probably available somewhere, but might be hard to find for Android since it might differ based on OS version / device. If you want things to be consistent as possible, I'd highly recommend setting your own timeout.